# With which spell did Harry Potter kill Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

As I've seen in the movie *Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows (part - 2)*, Voldemort's last spell produced a green light. I think it was *Avada Kedavra*. On the other hand, Harry's spell which was locked with it was reddish. Harry's spell destroyed Voldemort's body slowly after Voldemort cried for a while.

From what is shown in the movie franchise and documented on the [Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Killing_Curse),

- *Avada Kedavra* produces a green, not reddish, light.
- *Avada Kedavra* doesn't destroy the body of the victim.
- Death by *Avada Kedavra* is instant and painless.

This suggests that Harry's spell which killed Voldemort wasn't *Avada Kedavra*. Then, what spell was that?

Comment: Now don't you be destroying Harry's only truly heroic moment. He cast THE Mofo Expelliarmus, which does work as described, right after having crushed Avada Kedavra. :-)

Comment: Voldemort was ultimately destroyed by his own Avada Kedavra backfiring, as it was cast through the Elder Wand, which had it's alliance towards Harry

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Harry used his signature dueling spell: *Expelliarmus*. Due to a combination of the Elder Wand's true owner being Harry, not Voldemort, and the spells colliding, Voldemort's *Avada Kedavra* rebounded upon him (again). Since at that point all of his horcruxes had been destroyed there was nothing to keep him alive.

> Harry heard the high voice shriek as he too yelled his best hope to the heavens, pointing Draco’s wand: 
>   “Avada Kedavra!” 
>   “Expelliarmus!”

Then:

> Harry saw Voldemort’s green jet meet his own spell, saw the Elder Wand fly high ...  spinning through the air toward the master it would not kill, who had come to take full possession of it at last.

And:

> Tom Riddle hit the floor with a mundane finality, his body feeble and shrunken, the white hands empty, the snakelike face vacant and unknowing. Voldemort was dead, killed by his own rebounding curse, and Harry stood with two wands in his hand, staring down at his enemy’s shell.
>   
>   <sub>Chapter Thirty-Six, *The Flaw in the Plan* - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I haven't seen the last two movies but it seems as though the final scenes differ from the books pretty substantially. As the quotes above state, Voldemort's death is instant (as you'd expect from *Avada Kedavra*) and his body remains intact.

Comment: I don't remember the details either, but I remember that the movie ending changed a *lot* from the book ending, including (IIRC) making Voldemort fall off a cliff at the end (to make his death look more PG-friendly I guess).

Comment: Voldemort's actual death in the movie has him disintegrating. However, there's a scene before that where Harry's basically buying time for his friends to kill Nagini, where Harry bear-hugs Voldemort and throws them both off the top of the Astronomy Tower. That might be what @sundar's thinking of.

Comment: The differences between the book and movie from the moment Harry regains consciousness in the Forbidden Forest are tweaked to draw out the suspense a little more. The entire battle, actually, plays out differently than it does in the book, though of course the major plot points are there. This answer is correct in that Harry's last spell against Voldemort is *Expelliarmus*, and the fact that, through all the events of the last two books, Harry ended up the master of the Elder Wand, the wand wouldn't kill its own master.

Comment: If I am asking from movie perspective, is this a loophole?

Comment: @SachinShekhar I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Is what a loophole? However, without any explicit evidence that the movies differ from the books on this point as well, I think we probably have to conclude that the answer for the movies is the same and it's just not explicitly stated.

Comment: Voldemort's body was destroyed and he felt pain..

Comment: IIRC in *Deathly Hallows II* the movie, the final time Voldemort and Harry cast spells at one another, neither says anything. They just aim and cast. So *technically*, in the movie, Harry destroyed Voldemort with an unnamed spell. Please correct me if I'm remembering incorrectly. In the book, yes, it is Expelliarmus. I actually think I will check my *Deathly Hallows 2* BD and see.

Answer (score 15):

Okay, you asked about the *movie* and tagged this post "movie" so that is what standpoint I'm going to answer from.

The final casting of spells starts at around 2:26. Neither Voldemort nor Harry incant any spell at all. They just aim and cast their spells nonverbally. So technically the answer is the spell Harry used to defeat and kill Voldemort in the movie is unknown. As I mentioned in my comment, and Anthony Grist points out in his answer, in the book it is Expelliarmus.

I did note that when Voldemort lost his wand in the movie scene, the Elder Wand sails through the air from Voldemort to Harry. This might be indicative of Expelliarmus, although if you compare that to other uses of Expelliarmus in the movies, Expelliarmus usually just flings a wizard's wand away in a random direction. *That* said, in the movie *Deathly Hallows I*, Hermione disarms Mundungus Fletcher with Expelliarmus and Dung's wand does sail through the air to Hermione and she catches it. But getting back to Harry and Voldemort, technically no spell is said outloud by either.

Comment: perhaps it needs skillful casting of Expelliarmus to make the wand go a certain direction instead of flying away haphazardly

Comment: It is explained in the book that the wand flies to Harry because he is the right owner, and the Elder wand isn't just any wand.

Comment: @user13267 -- Sure, that's certainly possible. I personally think the spell is Expelliarmus, but was answering Sachin's question on a completely technical level. There was a lot of license taken in that scene for dramatic effect. :)

Comment: @Rob - All good points. :)

Comment: You are correct to answer from the view-point of the movie. +1

Comment: Also, Lupin disarms the trio with an Expelliarmus in the Shrieking Shack and catches the wands right?

Answer (score 0):

**In the movie**, and considering only canon from the movie series, it looks very much like Voldemort died because his last horcrux (Nagini) was killed. I'm going to get a lot of down votes for this, but there's literally no reason to think that Harry killed Voldemort *in the movie*.

1. Based on the visible evidence, Harry cast *Expelliarmus*. His spell was green, and when it reached Voldemort it did actually take away his wand. *The Disarming Charm* isn't a killing spell.
2. Based on the clip, after the green spell reaches Voldemort and expels the Elder wand, **it takes another 14 seconds** before Voldemort starts to disintegrate. If Harry's spell killed Voldemort, why did it take so long? Is it some special new slow-killing spell that he developed just for this battle? *Avada Kedavra* kills instantly evidently in the movies.
3. The idea of *Avada Kedavra* rebounding is from the books, and is *never seen or mentioned in the films*. Even if it did rebound, why would it take so long to take effect?
4. **Harry Potter has never killed anyone**. ([technically](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65440/did-harry-potter-ever-intentionally-kill)) This is a hero trope, and especially a movie trope, that the hero disarms/disables/etc the villain because of their personal code of Thou Shalt Not Kill ([like Batman..](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThouShaltNotKill)). I don't know why Hollywood thinks this way, but it seems to be pretty common that good-guy heroes will defeat villains without actively killing them. Maybe the villain kills themself. Maybe some other character kills them. Whatever, it seems to be attractive to leave the hero without a stain on their conscience.

Answer (score -8):

The only spell I know that could disintegrate someone would be Deletrius. Maybe he cast Deletrius while the movie followed the wand. I don't know!

Comment: This answer seems to be quite heavily based on speculation? Why do you suggest Deletrius when the top answers suggest otherwise?

Comment: Never heard of his spell.

Comment: Looks like a legit spell - http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Eradication_Spell

Comment: @Gallifreyan He knows the spell... Look at his username...